# docker login error Login: Account is not active. nexus repository

Tags: docker, nexus

I have hosted a nexus docker registry on a machine 10.232.208.199:8083 and i am trying to do a docker login from a remote redhat linux machine . 
i have added this registry to the daemon.json file

```
$ cat daemon.json
{
"insecure-registries" : ["10.232.208.199:8083","10.232.208.199:8084","10.232.208.199:8081","10.232.208.199:8085"]
}
```

when i am trying to perform a docker login i am getting below account not active error

```
docker login -u admin -p mypass 10.232.208.199:8083
Error response from daemon: Login: Account is not active. Please see the documentation of the registry http://10.232.208.199:8083/v1/ for instructions how to activate it.
```

Comment: Does the same username and password work in the NXRM UI?

Comment: yes, the user has roles and permissions to acces it and works from ui

Comment: Just to confirm, same issue if you don't use -u/-p and input at prompt?  Also ping works (e.g. curl -X GET -v -k 'https://localhost:8443/repository/docker1/v1/_ping' w/ your port/repo name there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem by following steps.

1)created a new docker repository .

2)in nexus created a new role with all acess for this docker repository

3)created a new user and assigned the new role to this new user.

4)in daemon.json added both ip and the **fully qualified machinename** in insecure registries.

```
daemon.json
{
"insecure-registries" : ["10.232.208.199:8083","machinename.fqdn:8083"]
}
```

after this worked

```
docker login -u **newuserwithdockerroles** -p mypass machinename.fqdn:8083
```